# Change spring datasource settings at runtime

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring web application which a user can deploy on their own servers.  Once the application is running, the adminstrator can set the database URL and credentials from the front end, and there is no default one set up. I do not know how to do this with spring / hibernate, as my datasource is wired in once the LocalSessionFacytoryBean is created in the initialisation of my spring container.

Comment: It doesn't appear you are using OSGi, but if you were, you could expose your DataSource as an osgi service and register/unregister those services (and their containing) bundles as needed to change your DatSource.

Comment: 'deploy for their institution': what does exactly mean? The will have a DB and some web server running on their servers and deploy your war on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application server supports it and its not to complicated for your users you could use JNDI datasources. They are configurable over the application server, however its not the same as changing them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `SessionFactory` object with a custom data source at runtime, and use that insted. Nothing stops you from that.

Comment: The problem with this is that my session factory cannot be wired in during the initialization of the spring container, as it is not set until a later date.  This means I must explicitly set the desired dependancies at runtime once the sesssion factory is created, or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, you can manually create everything, and then put it in spring

Comment: I am still not following you.  I would have to retrieve every bean that requires a session factory from my WebApplicationContext, then set that class field on every one once I have created it during runtime.  This does not seem like the most elegant way of doing things and breaks IOC in a sense - I would prefer to autowire in a session factory proxy of some sort, then just change the session factory on that proxy once it has been created.  Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: automatically - no. You'd have to create the proxy yourself

Comment: is there an example of a pattern I could follow to do this, or any part of the spring framework which would help?